# Weak Compactness in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I came across this statement

A set $X\subset L^1([0,1])$ is weakly relatively compact if for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that for every $A\subset [0,1]$ satisfying $\lambda(A)<\delta$ and every $f\in X$, $\int_A|f|d\lambda<\epsilon$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Does anyone know a proof of this?

Comment: This characterization of weakly relatively compact sets in $L^{1}$ is called the Dunford Pettis Theorem. Search the net for this theorem. One book containing  a detailed proof is Probability and Potentials by Paul Andre  Meyer.

Comment: You can find a proof in [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjwx8P8sMXiAhXpqlkKHYyxDJMQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FJorge_Hernandez_Hernandez%2Fpost%2FUniform_integrability%2Fattachment%2F59d655a979197b80779acc16%2FAS%253A526603123343360%25401502563376253%2Fdownload%2Funiform%2Bintegrability.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2YhMllD3KF9T64OQrsq4ee).